# Spring Data findFirstByLastNameIsNull() not working

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I've created a method in repository with name `findFirstByLastNameIsNull()`. Also you can see the database, I was expecting output '**UserFNanme5**', But I am getting empty output. Can anyone point out my mistake? Database is MySQL. Please see the screenshot attached.

[image]

Comment: I don't see any - I am suspecting that problem lies elsewhere.. try using some other query like findAll and see if the Repostiory works at all? Maybe you are connected to embedded database or something

Comment: Use @Query annotation over method and provide the query

Comment: Look in your debug logs, what query is logged? Do you use the right database connection?  Your code should work.

Comment: Looking at the database view, it looks like you have string value `NULL` stored in the last name column because `Null` displayed in row 7 looks different from your column values.